# How to detect smartcard insertion or removal event in linux

Tags: linux, events, smartcard, cac

Folks, I'm working on a certificate authentication app that will authenticate user based on CAC inserted. How do I know when the CAC is inserted / removed? I'll be "catching" that event in C++ or Java. Thanks.

Comment: For using Smartcard/USB Tokens in modern browsers, please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885   For CAC PKI Web Authentication, demo is available at https://web.signer.digital/home  Signer.Digital Browser Extension is free and available for all OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If you go for "low level" (which you apparently want to do) is to use PC/SC level (pcsc-lite) and the  [SCardGetStatusChange](http://pcsclite.alioth.debian.org/pcsc-lite/node20.html) function (or the equivalent in Java, what is [javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal.waitForCardPresent()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/jre/api/security/smartcardio/spec/javax/smartcardio/CardTerminal.html#waitForCardPresent(long)))
2. If you're working with higher level abstractions and go for PKCS#11 (and if your PKCS#11 provider implements it correctly), C_WaitForSlotEvent can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You might see if it is reported through `udev`.

Comment: And if not, it probably could be.

Comment: As a smart card will not show up as a device, why should it be reported via udev? Smart card readers (or USB tokens) that actually connect to a USB port are reported via udev but not smart cards (AFAIK)