# react-native digital signature with rsa-sha256

Tags: react-native, digital-signature

Help me!
I have been trying to fix this for 2 days but it was completely hopeless

```
signer = crypto.createSign('RSA-SHA256');
try {
    signer = signer.update(value);
    console.log(signer);
    signa = signer.sign(private_key, 'base64')
    console.log(signa)
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
}
signer.end();


console.log('Digital Signature: ', signa);

return signa
```

}

I'm use react-native-crypto.
This is what I got
[image: error]

Comment: Not able to see in your code, from where you are getting private_key. Are you trying to do this from browser? Is private_key present on server or client ? Browsers does not have access to local certificate/key store... Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885