# Digitally sign a Text file using USB Token using Asp.net/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, digital-signature

I have a USB token (Epass-Capricorn) and my requirement is to sign text/flat files using the same.

PS: I believe I have to get the "START-SIGNATURE", "START-CERTIFICATE" and "SIGNER-VERSION" data from the code and append at the end of the file, attached a screenshot of same.

Can someone guide me how can I achieve the same using C#?[image]

Comment: Since your tag contains asp.net and asp.net core it seems you are doing it from web application. Please refer this SO Post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885

Comment: @BharatVasant, i am doing the same using windows service, a web application to upload files for signing and windows service to automatically sign it.

Comment: Location of ePass Token matters..! Is the token connected to webserver ? Unlike your development environment, in case your UAT or Production server is on cloud then there might not be possibility of connecting USB token to your server.

Comment: @BharatVasant, Currently i have the ePass with me locally because i am yet developing the app, later the same would be attached to server where i would deploy this application. i am successful in signing the PDF files, however i am clueless on how to get the text/flat file signed.

Comment: I think you are confused or don't understand how digital signatures form USB Token works..! Since yours is web application, end user, acting through his browser needs to use his USB token and attach his signature.  How user can attach his token to server and sign?

Comment: @BharatVasant, no it is a common USB token for signature which is to be used to sign a particular type of document , user(across offices) will receive documents on their emails, they download the document upload it on server, the program digitally signs it and saves it in a folder for further sending.

Comment: @BharatVasant, epass 2003 is with me connected locally, using C# how can i sign a Text file, i dont want to encrypt the text file data but want to add the signing data to the file as shown in screenshot. Can you show me some path by which i can fetch the data or create the data of "START-SIGNATURE", "START-CERTIFICATE" and "SIGNER-VERSION" tags.