# Authentication Using Usb Token (example "Gemalto") For Spring Boot App

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, usb, token, gemalto

I have an web application that needs to Authenticate Users Using a Gemalto Usb Token , As i need to get the certificate stored in the usb to sign multiple Documents " Digital Signatures " , Any Ideas on how i could get this working .

I am using React Js / Spring Boot , Thanks

Comment: got the same question.. 
using React/NodeJS(Nest)

Comment: Jhon Born did you happen to resolve this? please share the result if yes.

Comment: Yes,  in order to solve this issue i used a library called https://fortifyapp.com/ that contains a node server that communicates directly with your js server as this app gets installed into the clients Pc and then you can get his public key or sign something with the private key

Comment: everything should be explained in there documentation , it is an open source app by the way

Comment: The requirement can also be achieved using Browser Extension. Refer SO answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885 for more details about Signer.Digital Browser Extension.