# Is it possible to enable smart card authentication for the build-in dialogs in Chrome and Firefox like in Microsoft´s Edge?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, smartcard

We have implemented an web application (ASP.NET 5) and enabled Windows Authentication in IIS.

The Edge browser prompts an authentication dialog which requests an username and password. The dialog provides an link "More choices" where we can authenticate via an smart card:

[image: Windows Autentication Edge - Smart Card]

We do not know if there is a special windows configuration which provides the smart card authentication in this dialog.

Unfortunately, Google Chrome and Firefox do not provide the authentication via smart card. Only password is provided:

[image: Windows Authentication Chrome]

Question: Is it possible to enable smart card authentication for the build-in dialogs in Chrome and Firefox like in Microsoft´s Edge?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried the method you are talking about but suggest you to try cross browser, cross platform solution by using Browser Extension.  Browser extension communicates with underlaying host running on client user's system to access (Windows) Certificate Store or (Win CSP & Linux/Mac PKCS#11) Smartcard connected locally.

Refer to point no. 3 of [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) to know how it works. Working sample of Smartcard User Web Authentication may be explored [Here](https://web.signer.digital/Home) and documentation [Here](http://help.signer.digital/digital_signing_and_authentication_from_web_browser.htm)

*To Register Certificate on Server:*

```
//Get Selected Certificate Information
try { 
    var CertInfo = await SignerDigital.getSelectedCertificate() ;           
}
catch(errmsg) {
            //Display Errmsg
}
```

*To authenticate or Login using Digital Signature:*

```
authToken = <userid>|<password>; //or say any user cetdentials or id
try {
    var SignData = await SignerDigital.signAuthToken(authToken, "SHA256");
//Post signed Data to server along with original authToken
}
catch (errMsg){
    //display errMsg.
}
```