# Problem with cURL in PKCS11 with USB TOKEN

Tags: curl, usb, token, pkcs#11, pkcs

I am trying to run a cURL on ubuntu on a usb authentication token to an URL.
I can see the private key when I run the command ''pkcs11-tool -l --pin  -O", while if I run the command on p11tool `p11tool --login --set-pin=<PIN> --list-all`, it returns `"Error in crt_list_import (1): PKCS #11 error."`
I also tried execute the following cURL `"curl --engine pkcs11 -E 'pkcs11:<URL>' https://<URL>'"` it returns me this log:

```
Login failed
Login to token failed, returning NULL...
curl: (58) ssl engine cannot load client cert with id '<URL>' [error:82074005:PKCS#11 module:pkcs11_login:General Error]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you are looking PKI Web application authentication using USB Token, refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885