# Request.GetClientCertificate sometimes returns incorrect information in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, ssl-certificate, smartcard

I have a .Net 4.6 Web Application running on IIS which reads smart cards to get user information.  In the beginning the application was working fine but after a few days other user's card information was showing up for different users.  For example someone nowhere near me or associated with me tried to login but my smart card information would show up as though it was read from their card.  It is almost like my smart card information is being cached on the server.

This is the code that reads the smart card information.

```
X509Certificate2 clientCert = new X509Certificate2(Request.GetClientCertificate());

u.Info = clientCert.Subject.ToString();
```

I just found out that if I restart IIS the credential that was showing will reset and the correct one will show.

Not sure what I am doing wrong that I am not getting the correct smart card information.

Thanks!!

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Are you trying to read certificate connected to client browser or from the server...?  For accessing certificate from client's device smartcard certificate in web application, please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being a static variable.

Static variables creates a single instance of a variable that is accessible by every application user.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).