# How i extract a certificate and a private key from a token with PKCS11 Interop LowLevele API

Tags: c#, certificate, token, pkcs#11, pkcs11interop

I have an application to sign a PDF file and I need to extract from token certificate and private key to do this.

I need a code in C# with `Pkcs11Interop` LowLevel API. I've tried with this code:

```
bool success = true; 
CK_ATTRIBUTE[] template = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[2]; 
template[0] = CkaUtils.CreateAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE); 
template[1] = CkaUtils.CreateAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true);
List<IObjectHandle> foundObjects = new List<IObjectHandle>();
CKR test = pkcs11.C_FindObjectsInit(SessionOpened, template, Convert.ToUInt32(template.Length));
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: bool success = true;

            CK_ATTRIBUTE[] template = new CK_ATTRIBUTE[2];
            template[0] = CkaUtils.CreateAttribute(CKA.CKA_CLASS, CKO.CKO_CERTIFICATE);
            template[1] = CkaUtils.CreateAttribute(CKA.CKA_TOKEN, true);
        
            



            List<IObjectHandle> foundObjects = new List<IObjectHandle>();


            CKR test = pkcs11.C_FindObjectsInit(SessionOpened, template, Convert.ToUInt32(template.Length));

Comment: if you want to use smartcard/token in the web application, check answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885