# Sign hash using CADES-BES signature using USB token

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, digital-signature, pkcs#11

under the regulation of the e-invoicing in Egypt, the invoices must be electronically signed before submission.
I have been trying to follow the steps in there website: [here](https://sdk.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/signature-creation/)
but I dont have much experience in this field and I dont find enough resources in that link to create the e-signature from the usb token on the hashed value.

Comment: In case you are looking to sign from modern browser, you may find some points in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885  answer useful...!

Comment: We have added support for Digital Signature as per Egypt ITIDA CAdES-BES standard in Signer.Digital offerings.

Comment: Refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885 for Javascript APIs for signing as per Egypt ITIDA CAdES-BES

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Signer.Digital Browser Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signerdigital-digital-sig/glghokcicpikglmflbbelbgeafpijkkf) provided from [Signer.Digital](https://signer.digital) completely free.

Download and Install complete setup (just 1.65 MB) Signer.Digital Browser Extension host form [CNet Download](https://download.cnet.com/Signer-Digital-Chrome-Extension/3000-33362_4-78042540.html)

Use below Javascript in your html page code to get CAdES-BES Signature as per ITIDA Egypt standards for Egypt eInvoicing:

`SignResult = await SignerDigital.signHashCAdESEg(<hash of your Json or XML>);`

Pass *certThumbPrint* parameter to above method to select Certificate Silently without opening Certificate Selection dialog.

Comment: The extension doesn't function any more.

Comment: Extension is working... Please Don't post such short comments... write what error you are getting or seek help from our helpdesk...

Comment: After installing the extension on an updated Chrome browser and restarting it, clicking on the extension icon does nothing, if you check extension comments, I'm not the only person with this issue.

Comment: This extension provides JavaScript API that a web-developer needs to integrate in it's webpage...!!  This extension is not for stand-alone end users...!  We will update this as message on clicking extension icon in the browser...

Comment: Yes, that will be helpful. Thanks for clarifying, will try it again.

Comment: Updated version 3.2.2 now has popup on clicking Extension Icon in Extension Toolbar in Chrome and Edge... Will also update in Firefox.  Thanks.