# Signing JSON file using usb token (X509 certificate) in asp.net

Tags: certificate, digital-signature, signing

I want digitally sign a json file , the file should like in the below format.
[input file will be in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLhcp.png)

The output i am accepting after the sign it should appear like below.
[The desired output expected in this format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sR4AZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

For web application, you need to use Browser Extension to use local USB Token connected to user's device.  Refer to complete JavaScript API of free Signer.Digital Browser Extension used by half a million users in India and globally: [Accessing ePass2003 Auto token through browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885)

Use API: getSelectedCertificate and signHash or signHashCms as per your project requirements.