# Smartcard authentication using Django

Tags: python, django, pki

Is there a way to enable CAC authentication with Django?  I've been looking at articles stating to use OpenSSL, pkcs11, etc, but no clue on how to actually get python to parse x509 certificates.

Goal is to be able to authenticate users via their smart cards on a custom django web server i'm building out.

So far, I've gotten it to work locally by using bash pkcs11-tool to parse cac certs, but no clue on how to do this server-side if a user was to browse to my webserver to be prompted for a cac cert.  hope this makes sense.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you require PKI web authentication similar to [this](https://web.signer.digital/Home) ? If yes, you may refer to [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) which you can use to sign authtoken on browser and verify on server...