# How to sign an Excel file received from the server using EDS on the client?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, digital-signature

Need your help:
I have a web application (back - .NetCore; front - Angular).

How to sign an Excel file generated on the server using an EDS on a client? It's required that, as a result, the user can receive the signed document and the digital signature is visible inside when he open the .xls file.
In addition, using a separate button, I need to be able to save the document in PDF with a visible signature that contained the full name, date and time
Documents NOT signed with EDS in .xls and .pdf formats are created on the server. But how to embed a digital signature in them on the client?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question has tags *angular* and *asp.net-core*, I assume that you are talking about web application and by *client*, you mean web browser.  If that is the case, you require Browser Extension on browser.  If you are talking about thick client application, you require equivalent agent on client.

For modern browsers as client, please refer to [Accessing ePass2003 Auto token through browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885).  This applies equally to EDS on USB token or Smartcard or in Windows Local Certificate Store.