The IIS server is unable to access the etoken device

I used the Asp.net core web API to create a file signing server
Users can post files to the server, and the server will call signtool.exe to connect to the local USB token to sign the files, and then return them to the client for download

I run the service using

dotnet MyWebApi.DLL --urls=http://localhost:22000

and successfully tested it. The signature was successfully invoked on the server and the signature was successful！
However, after deploying this web service on IIS, I found that the certificate was not recognized and the signature failed. Display in the log:no certificates were found that met
After searching for some relevant information, I modified the permissions of the application pool, but still couldn't function properly like running the dotnet command directly

Excuse me, how should I configure iis?
just now,I try to deploy it as a WindowsService  and it's also throw a error......

There are fundamental differences when running the same code on IIS, https://docs.lextudio.com/blog/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You need the token vendor to tell you more about how to use it with IIS.

Please check the validity period of the certificate, as most certificates have an expiration date. This problem may occur if the certificate has expired.

expiration date at 2026

For web application, refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885
