Encryption and decryption using ePass3003 USB token device
I have a ePass3003 USB token device, it seems there are public and private keys defined on the device.
I'm trying to find a way to encrypt and decrypt text using asymetric Encryption methods with the keys on the device in my C# application, but I haven't found a solid solution to this.
What are the best practices to this issue and where should I even start from?
You help is highly appreciated!

Is this a desktop application or web application. For web application and USB token connected to user's device acting through modern web browser like Chrome, Edge, Firefox, please refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885
