How to Sign a JSON Using USB DSC Hardware
I am working on a project where I need to sign a JSON object using a Digital Signature Certificate (DSC) stored on a USB token.
I understand that the private key is not directly extractable from the hardware for security reasons. Instead, the signing operation should be performed by the DSC hardware itself.
Here’s what I need help with:
Accessing the DSC Hardware:
What tools or libraries are needed to interact with USB DSC hardware? How can I communicate with the USB token to perform signing?
I tried using C# code to sign JSON with a USB DSC hardware, but it didn’t work

If you want to do it from web application (client end) i.e. modern web browser, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885
